# How to use Kaniko on the local kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kaniko

I use kubernetes on docker for windows.
And I want to use Kaniko but I could not build an image on local kubernetes.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y ssh
```

kanikopod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
spec:
  containers:
    - image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest
      args: 
      - --dockerfile=/mnt/Dockerfile 
      - --context= /mnt
      - --no-push
      name: kaniko
      command:
        - sleep
        - infinity
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt
          name: mount-volume

  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
    - name: mount-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: kaniko-workspace
```

But ContainerCannotRun error occurred.

kubectl describe pods kaniko
result is

```
Name:               kaniko
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               docker-desktop/192.168.65.3
Start Time:         Mon, 06 May 2019 18:13:47 +0900
Labels:             <none>
Annotations:        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Pod","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"kaniko","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"containers":[{"args":["--dock...
Status:             Pending
IP:
Containers:
  kaniko:
    Container ID:
    Image:         gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sleep
      infinity
    Args:
      --dockerfile=/mnt/Dockerfile
      --context= /mnt
      --no-push
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /mnt from mount-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-spjnr (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mount-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  kaniko-workspace
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-spjnr:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-spjnr
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  4s    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/kaniko to docker-desktop
```

kubectl logs kaniko
But there was no output.

I think "--destination=" option is needed for kaniko, but I cannot find the information.
What should I do?

Comment: can you update the question with the output of below command `kubectl logs kaniko`

Comment: kubectl logs kaniko  
But there was no output. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: kubect get pods output please

Comment: In my yaml, command section was not needed. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this lines:

```
  command:
    - sleep
    - infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

My home-lab work-around where my Gitea instance doesn't have a TLS cert:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kaniko
  namespace: kaniko
  labels:
    name: kaniko
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kaniko
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kaniko
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: shared-data
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: kaniko
        image: 192.168.2.22:5000/pg/kaniko:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-data
          mountPath: /workspace
        args: ["--dockerfile=Dockerfile",
               "--context=dir:///workspace",
               "--destination=192.168.2.22:5000/tc5/gitea:latest"]
      initContainers:
        - name: debian-container
          image: 192.168.2.22:5000/pg/gitbot
          volumeMounts:
          - name: shared-data
            mountPath: /workspace
          command: ["git"]
          args: ["clone",
                 "http://192.168.2.111/tim/gitea",
                 "/workspace"]
```

The command and args at the end of the init container is the equivalent of:

```
git clone http://192.168.2.111/tim/gitea /workspace
```

Pulling the code doesn't need to use git.  You can use other tools to pull the code (scp, wget, curl, etc.).  The working piece in the manifest is where the volume is defined and shared between the two containers.

In the above, I use a local copy of the Kaniko image, to avoide having to pull from Google's repo (which is migrating to another solution soon).

The gitbot container is just a Ubuntu 22.04 container with bash, git, and vim installed. Since it's an initContainer, it's run once before Kaniko is allowed to execute.

```
From ubuntu:22.04
RUN touch /tmp/shim-20231227
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y git bash vim
COPY startup.sh /startup.sh
RUN chmod a+x /startup.sh
CMD ["/startup.sh"]
```

And the start up script amounts to:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash -c "while true; do sleep 30; done;"
```

There's probably a way to replace certain portions of the larger manifest, so that it can be used wherever it's needed.  Because it's a home lab, I just include a customized version in each of my projects' folders.

Lastly, your use of "--no-push" prevents Kaniko from pushing the resulting image.